# Not able to run spring boot mvn test cases while using MySQL DB on Jenkins server

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to the Jenkins server and am currently testing it out. However, I am encountering an error with the following scenario:

I have a Spring Boot application with a MySQL database, and I am attempting to run a test case on the Jenkins server. Unfortunately, the Jenkins server is unable to connect to the MySQL database.

To troubleshoot the issue, I am adding the following step for testing purposes:

```
stage('Run the test cases'){
    steps{
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '4a632d56-baf5-4455-90fe-21e6823f58f1', passwordVariable: 'password', usernameVariable: 'user')]) {
        sh "mysql connection"
        sh "mysql -h 192.168.112.2 -umaninder -pmaninder"
        sh "connection testing done"
        sh "mvn test"
    }
    }
}
```

I have mentioned the IP address of the machine on which my MySQL Server is installed and I am able to connect with MySQL DB if I use the same command on Jenkins machine terminal but somehow here it is getting failed.

**Error:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)**

Any help would be really appeciated:

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like perhaps your Spring code is trying to connect to some **local** MySQL instance? i.e. your `application-test.properties` Spring config is not using a remote server? `mysql -h` has nothing to do with your `mvn test` command...

In any case, connecting to external instances for tests is not recommended (for the exact reason you are seeing - if the database is unavailable for any reason, you cannot deploy anything).  If your Jenkins instances have Docker available, you can use [TestContainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/) to start/run/stop a whole database server as part of your tests.

Otherwise, depending on your test coverage needs, you can mock the Spring Repository objects and query results, and trust that the library you're really using at runtime will always do the correct thing.